# Dynamic values and parameters in url or cookies query, how to?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, cookies

I am trying to figure out how to add, change or remove values and parameters in specific parts of query.

I have a cookie `$.cookie('productsInBasket', '&i=' + productId + '&q=' + productQty + '&c=' + productSize);` where productId, productQty and productSize should be added and removed dynamically.

So it can be `&i=2441&q=1&c=2521` or `&i=2441,2442,2443&q=1&c=2521` or `&i=2441,2442,2443&q=1,3,14&c=2521,2522,2523` or... well you've got the point.

What would be the way to achieve that?

Thank you!

P.S. That should be jQuery or Javascript solution.

Comment: @JapanPro as happy I am for any answer... but maybe you can give some libraries suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I will not say that my way is right, but this is mine own workaround.

I simple create 4 cookies, 3 for &i=, &q=, &c= and 4th for merging them together.

The code for that is:

```
$.cookie('productsInBasketItems', productId);
$.cookie('productsInBasketQty', productQty);
$.cookie('productsInBasketColors', productSize);

$.cookie('productsInBasketMerge', '&i=' + $.cookie('productsInBasketItems') + '&q=' + $.cookie('productsInBasketQty') + '&c=' + $.cookie('productsInBasketColors'));
```

That way I can manipulate each of the value and its options across my pages.

Of course I think there is more elegant ways as .split() inside .split(), but my knowledge does not allow me to spend much time on that.

Hope that will help anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have your values in arrays,

```
​var i = [1,2,3];
var q = [5,10,15];
var c = [100,200,300];
```

A simple function can build your cookie from the arrays:

```
function createCookie(i,q,c){
    return ("&i="+i.join(',')+"&q="+q.join(',')+"&c="+c.join(','));
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Fv2St/)